# Posting second photo to album using Facebook graph API

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I've uploaded the first photo to facebook graph API working useing C# Facebook SDK toolkit.

```
fb.Post("me/photos", upload)
```

However, when I trying and upload a second file, it errors out with error 500. If I delete the apps photo album that was created, the upload works.

Question: Does the posting to me/photos work for the second photo or do I need to lookup the Apps default album ID and post it directly to that album for the second photo?

Comment: I had the same problem until I switch from using a test user to a real user.